# What is correct way for redirect non language code URLs to language code contained URL in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

My website's old URLs for products in (just) EN was:

**{domain}/product/{permalink}**

I want to redirect them to:

**{domain}/en/product/{permalink}**

According to other languages were:

**{domain}/{de|fr|es}/product/{permalink}**

What I tried to do is:

```
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("redirect-rule/(.*)", "redirected/$1/");

app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

Old URLs to be remained:

**{domain}/{de|fr|es|...}/product/{permalink}**

Just one pattern to be changed:

**{domain}/product/{permalink} to {domain}/en/product/{permalink}**

What is the correct REGEX I have to use in redirect rules?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to just redirect the {domain}/product/{permalink} to {domain}/en/product/{permalink} and keep other url, I sugest you could try to use below redirect regex.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRedirect(@"^product/(.*)", "en/product/$1");

        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks @brando-zhang but didn't work, before any action the path changed to 404 not found because RouteValueRequestCultureProvider excepts language code in URL. empty or wrong URL makes request as not found.

Comment: You mean it will firstly be captured the RouteValueRequestCultureProvider and return 404 error to client?

Comment: yes exactly, because project contains multi culture support